# Java Set of type POJO not able to add elements

Tags: java, collections, set

I've a data object class:

```
public class MyDataObject {
  private String value;
  private String text;
  private Set<MyDataObject> child;

  // Getter & setters

  // Constructor
  public MyDataObject(final String value, final String text) {
    this.value = value;
    this.text = text;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    MyDataObject that = (MyDataObject) o;
    return value.equals(that.value) &&
            text.equals(that.text) &&
            Objects.equals(child, that.child);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(value, text, child);
  }
}
```

I'm adding 2 child elements in one of my `MyDataObject` object.

Say:

```
MyDataObject myDataObject = new MyDataObject("USA", "United States");
Set<MyDataObject> childSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(MyDataObject::getText));
childSet.add(new MyDataObject("NY", "Bronx"));      // This is added
childSet.add(new MyDataObject("NY", "Manhattan"));  // This is not being added, returing false.
myDataObject.setChild(childSet);
```

I've overridden `hashcode` and `equals` method as well to consider child element.

What am I missing?

Comment: `childSet.add("NY", "Bronx");` this is invalid , should be `childSet.add(new MyDataObject("NY", "Bronx"))`and I can't reproduce you issue

Comment: @Eklavya, sorry for the typos. I was manually typing it. Question updated.

Comment: I can't reproduced your issue https://onlinegdb.com/S1jloiDC8

Answer (score 2):

Your `Comparator` is not [consistent with equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).

That is: you have selected a `Comparator` for your `Set` that returns `0` in cases where your `equals(Object)` method returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you mentioned can be reproduced by `Comparator.comparing(MyDataObject::getValue)`. Nevertheless, both the comparators `Comparator.comparing(MyDataObject::getText)` and `Comparator.comparing(MyDataObject::getValue)` are inconsistent with the `equals`. See the javadoc of [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) where this is mentioned.

```
    final Comparator<MyDataObject> myDataObjectComparator = Comparator.comparing(MyDataObject::getValue);
    final MyDataObject myDataObject1 = new MyDataObject("NY", "Bronx");
    final MyDataObject myDataObject2 = new MyDataObject("NY", "Manhattan");
    System.out.println(myDataObject1.equals(myDataObject2));
    System.out.println(myDataObjectComparator.compare(myDataObject1, myDataObject2));
```

Note that the `equals` say that the objects are not equal while `compareTo` gives `0`. For the same two objects.

Answer (score 0):

I am changed a little your code. `childSet.add` expect object but you send two strings. This resolve work for me.

```
    MyDataObject myDataObject = new MyDataObject("USA", "United States");
    Set<MyDataObject> childSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(MyDataObject::getText));
    MyDataObject myDataObject1 = new MyDataObject("NY", "Bronx");
    MyDataObject myDataObject2 = new MyDataObject("NY", "Manhattan");
    childSet.add(myDataObject1);        // This is added
    childSet.add(myDataObject2);    // This is not being added, returing false.
    myDataObject.setChild(childSet);

    myDataObject.getChild()
            .stream()
            .map(child -> child.getValue() + " " + child.getText())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```